# vba insert validation list - error 1004 when worksheet locked?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following vba code which works fine; however, it doesn't work when I lock/protect my worksheet, even though I have unticked 'locked' for the relevant cells within the cell format options.

Why I am getting

> error 1004 application defined or object defined error

when the worksheet is locked?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Range("B10").Value <> "" Then
        Dim MyList(9) As String
        MyList(0) = "60 Days EOM"
        MyList(1) = "60 Days DOI"
        MyList(2) = "45 Days EOM"
        MyList(3) = "45 Days DOI"
        MyList(4) = "30 Days EOM"
        MyList(5) = "30 Days DOI"
        MyList(6) = "14 Days DOI"
        MyList(7) = "10 Days EOM"
        MyList(8) = "7 Days DOI"
        MyList(9) = "Immediate Payment"
        With Range("N38").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
        End With
        If Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("N38")) Is Nothing Then
            Range("N38").Value = "60 Days EOM"
        End If
    Else
        Range("N38").Validation.Delete
        Range("N38").Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the simplest solution would be to unlock the sheet @ the start of your code and lock it at the end.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that even though you unlocked the cells, Data Validation is still off limits.  You have to unprotect the sheet before you apply data validation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set validation when protection is enabled.

What I do is remove protection at start of procedure and add it back in at the end, remembering error handling which should set the protection back on in the case of failure.

I often create a class which applies protection.

Say a class called cProtect

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Sheet1.Unprotect
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Sheet1.Protect
End Sub
```

And in my procedure I start with:

```
Dim protect as cProtect
Set protect = new cProtect
```

This causes the protection to be removed via the class initialize method, and then when the instance goes out of scope for any reason (procedure ends, errors), the terminate fires and protection gets applied back on it.